# Turn ON LED and OFF using GPIO pins on RPI

Tags: gpio, pi-2, hardware

I am a new PI owner and was thinking is it possible to wire a button and LED to the GPIO pins so that when the button is pressed, the LED turns on.
Can you please guide me on what hardware I need if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 for lack of effort a simple google search would return several pages like this one https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/worksheet/

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that some research effort is expected here (which is why your question got a minus one even as a typed this comment). This particular questions sound vey likely to have been asked before. Please use the search first. Also: check the [MagPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/) for some inspiration and plenty of tutorials (covering this basics). Really worth a look!

Comment: This is one of the most basic tasks a new Pi owner can undertake. Why did you buy a Pi in the first place if you didn't even know this was possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google will give you the response quite easily, but I'll bite. You'll need:

- A Breadboard
- A 330 ohm resistor
- Two Male-Female jumper wires

You could skip the breadboard, but it would definitely make things easier for you if you would use it.

Just google "raspberry pi light led" without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this video as a guide through your start with Rpi:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL_oZGHLHvU&ab_channel=DroneBotWorkshop
I strongly recommend this creator, he pays attention to what is happening and explains everything step by step.

Or use this simple code with the presented setup:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LED_PIN = 18
BUTTON_PIN = 26

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN) == GPIO.HIGH:
        GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

[image: Set up:]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130791)